# Perform Segue from other class

Tags: ios, swift, segue

I would like to perform segue from another class.

```
class A {
    func createAccount(email:String,password:String) {
        if email != "" && password != "" {
            B().performSegueFromA(id: "Test")
        }
    }
}

class B: UIViewController {
    var a = A()

    @IBAction func CreateAccountButton(_ sender: Any) {
        A.createAccount(email: newEmailField.text!, password: newPasswordField.text!)
    }

    func performSegueFromA(id:String) {
        self.performSegue(withIdentifier: id, sender: nil)
    }
}
```

I am calling  `performSegueFromA` method from class A. However I am getting  reason:

> 'Receiver has no segue with identifier 'Test''

I have the segue identifier set in the `mainstoryboard`.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: It depends upon how you instantiate the class `B` and on it's lifecycle.

Comment: @RatulSharker Thank you for your comment,  class B is inheriting from UIViewController. class A is the model for class B.

Comment: How do you instantiating `B` & exactly when `A` call the `performSegue` function ?

Comment: @RatulSharker I have updated my question! I am using perform for my create account screen.

Comment: I think there is a weird cycle in your code... Why would you do such an implementation? Do you think *Delegation* might be better in your case?

Comment: I think you problem lies in the miss-understanding of how objects are created and their lifecycle.  For example in class B you define an instance variable called `a` but then never use it at all.  In the `CreateAccountButton` method of class B so create a new version of class A which you use to call `createAccount` and then that goes out of scope and is destroyed.  In the `createAccount` method of class A you once again create a new instance of class B and use that.

Comment: You can use a delegation pattern between A and B so that your B instance can invoke the method on the correct instance of A

Comment: What the error is actually telling you is that regardless of the code there is no segue with the identifier of 'Test'.  Check that one exists in your storyboard and has the identifier set correctly and that the class instance of 'B' has actually come from that storyboard as well so that it knows where to look for it.